# Excel VBA adding Spaces form Str()

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have the following snipet in Excel 2013/VBA. The code is a very simple random cell/row generator which then displays the output in a text box. In the snippet below Excel/Vba is adding a space between A and the random numebr for example:

"A 14"

where the expected out put was

"A14"

I've gotten around this using the `Replace()` function, however I'm wondering why this behaviour occurs i the first place. Is it to do with the `Str()` function?

```
Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CenRaw")

Dim k As Long
Dim selectedRow As String

k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
aRandNum = Int((k - 2) * Rnd + 2)
selectedRow = Replace("A" & Str(aRandNum), " ", "")
tbOne.Text = selectedRow
selectedRow = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this article on MSDN:

[vba str leading spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290359)

The easier way is to use: `LTrim$(aRandNum)`

Answer (score 3):

VBA already has a function for casting to string that doesn't include leading spaces:

```
tbOne.Text = "A" & CStr(aRandNum)
```

There are similar functions for casting to other data types too:

- CBool() -> Boolean
- CInt() -> Integer
- CLng() -> Long
- CDbl() -> Double
- CDate() -> Date
- CDec() -> Decimal

to name just a few other examples

Although if you're working with a textbox, the value being assigned is implicitly a string and so the numeric value would show as a string anyway.